Using .Net/RestSharp/Polly how do I get serialized body content before calling execute on the RestClient
I’m developing a vb.net application targeting .Net Framework 4.8 using RestSharp and Polly and I trying to gzip the request that is being sent.
My understanding is if I can get hold of the serialized body then I can use something like
...
IRestResponse restResponse;

var dataStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(dataStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(zipStream))
{
    writer.Write(serializedBody);
}

var compressedBytes = dataStream.ToArray();

request.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/x-gzip", compressedBytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);

restResponse = client.Post(request);
...

How do I get the serializedBody so I can do this?
I have tried using the RestRequest's OnBeforeRequest property to get the request body
Inside my property I use
await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

that returns the bytes I want but then I can't replace the existing HttpContent body with the GZIPed version of those (everything I try appears to append to the existing HttpContent body)
I was expecting to be able to replace the HttpContent body.
Also I'm using Polly to retry twice on failure and using Fiddler what I'm seeing is that the API call is done twice using the uncompressed bytes before a single attempt at using the new HttpContent which fails

This code does not seem like it is Visual Basic.

Sorry, but it is unclear what exactly do you want to achieve. Could you please explain that part as well?

The code sample above is in C# and so I know I need to do the equivalent of that in Visual Basic; that's not a problem I can do that.
I have found that I can intercept the code another way and I can use the same json serializer that RestSharp uses to create the json equivalent body from DTOs. I can gzip that, fiddler recognizes it and the server is responding.
My current issue is that I can't do the same for API calls that have form parameters
